# How can we detect a proxy/virtual mobile number?

Tags: sms

To filter scammers, we validate user accounts with a sms verification system.

As you can imagine, some people are using virtual numbers.

Some [MCCMNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code) can easily be banned as they are favored by scammers. But most scammer numbers have the MCCMNC of a "clean" telco.

How can we detect that?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Nexmo Verify API](https://www.nexmo.com/verify/) to confirm that a phone number is valid, reachable and accessible by your user. Landline and mobile phones can be verified, while virtual and toll free numbers will be rejected. Trial service offers you 20 free verifications.

They have another product, [Number Insight](https://www.nexmo.com/product/number-insight/), which can be used to determine if a telephone number is a mobile phone, landline, virtual number or a Premium/Toll-Free number.

Comment: Is there any API of Google to Identify virtual number?